# cut command from 2 different rows

Tags: bash

my code below extracts 'Country' but how would I also extract the 'city' in the
second row?

```
geoiplookup 212.58.246.82 | grep Country | cut -c 28-45
```

---

```
GeoIP Country Edition: GB, United Kingdom
GeoIP City Edition, Rev 1: GB, N7, Tadworth, N/A, 51.283298, -0.233300, 0, 0
GeoIP City Edition, Rev 0: GB, N7, Tadworth, N/A, 51.283298, -0.233300
```

I want my output to look like this -> city, Country

for example: Tadworth, United Kingdom

My code currently just gives me United Kingdom

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about what you're trying to do?  In your example, you're extracting data by column number from lines of comma-separated output.  There are probably better ways to do whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your `output`.

Comment: You might want to look into `awk` for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `geoiplookup` is producing comma-separated output.  Trying extract data by column numbers, as you're doing with the `cut` command, is going to be very fragile.  `cut` with field seperators -- or `awk`, or a high-level scripting language -- is going to be more flexible.  For example, the following `awk` script will do approximately what you want:

```
  BEGIN {FS=":"}

  /GeoIP Country Edition/ {
          split($2, parts, ", ")
          country_code=parts[1]
          country_name=parts[2]
          }

  /GeoIP City Edition/ {
          split($2, parts, ", ")
          city_name=parts[3]

          printf "%s, %s\n", city_name, country_name
          }
```

We first split each line into a label and data separated by a `:`.
Then within the data, we split on `,` and extract the relevant fields.

Comment: larsks, nicely done. I can see you've been scripting for awhile now. This will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
geoiplookup 212.58.246.82 | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr "\n" ","
```